# Python selenium can't click on a checkbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing python selenium code to automatic fill the form for testing purpose. But my code always throw exception when I try to click a checkbox. This is the HTML checkbox code:

```html
<div
  id="isManuallyEnterYourAddress"
>
  <div class="field-wrapper">
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="myId"
        id="myId"
        value="true"
        class="input-field__checkbox"
        alias="isManuallyEnterYourAddress"
      />
      <input
        type="hidden"
        name="myId"
        value="false"
      />

      <label
        for="myId"
      >
        manually enter your address
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my first try, it's work before but it's crash now, I don't know why

```py
manual_address_1 = driver.find_element(
        By.ID, "myId"
    )
    manual_address_1.click()
```

I got this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (337, 1425)`
I also try the others way, like WebDriverWait, but it still exception

```
manual_address_2 = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='myId']")
        )
    )
```

Or find by label:

```py
manual_address_1 = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//label[@for='myId']")
        )
    )
```

Or try ActionChains:

```py
action.move_to_element(manual_address_1).click().perform()
```

but I got the error: `selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move the target out of bounds`

What's wrong? This checkbox is clearly visible, I can click no problem by mouse

Comment: This not debuggable if you do not confirm the page url', or alternatively provide the *full* page url.

Comment: MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException  means that the element you are looking for is not within the Viewport. maybe you need to scroll into it

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus sorry I can't provide the page url

Comment: @AbdelYsf scroll_to_element() got the same error with move_to_element(): `selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds`

Answer (score 1):

When a regular selenium click doesn't work, you may be able to use the selenium `execute_script()` way:

```py
element = driver.find_element("css selector", "#myId")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```